# CCSpriteBatchNode is deprecated Cocos2d 3.1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a problem following a tutorial for cocos2d 3.0 in cocos2d 3.1 ... when compilation finish show a warning  "CCSpriteBatchNode is deprecated", how can I use the plist now? or isn't used now in cocos2d 3.1? can you write an example, would very helpful :)

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    CCSpriteBatchNode *_batchNode; // WARNING 1 HERE
    Hunter *_hunter;
    Bird *_bird;
}

-(void)addBackground
{
    //1
    CGSize viewSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;
    //2
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"game_scene_bg.png"];
    //3
    background.position = ccp(viewSize.width  * 0.5f, viewSize.height * 0.5f);
    //4
    [self addChild:background];
}

-(void)createBatchNode {
    //1
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Cocohunt.plist"];
    //2
    _batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Cocohunt.png"];  // WARNING 2 HERE
    //3
    [self addChild:_batchNode z:1];

}
```

Comment: Solved, look here :) ... http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/ccspritebatchnode-is-deprecated-in-v3-1/14216/8

Answer (score 0):

In version 3.1, the cocos2d renderer was re-made to automatically batch drawn sprites. So CCSpriteBatchNode is no longer needed, just use a CCNode.

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    CCNode *_batchNode; // WARNING 1 HERE
    Hunter *_hunter;
    Bird *_bird;
}
```